# Replace a string with wildcard in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch file and I need skip 'echo' of some lines. Lines that I want to skip are:

```
W;;
A;;TE;Tr100;8;;31.79;SHIP-TE50;;
A;;TE;Tr100;8;;33.08;SHIP-TE50;;
and so on .
```

I want to use only `A;;TE;Tr100;` and then wildcard to catch the line and skip displaying it. It works for `W;;` but it does not work for `A;;TE;`
How could I do it?

```
@ECHO OFF    
cls

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a number=%1-1
SET "sourcedir=z:\abc\def\ghi"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\jklm%number%.gwl"
SET "last="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('sort "%filename1%"') DO (
 IF "%%a"=="W;;" goto :break
 IF "%%a"=="A;;TE;*" goto :break 
 IF "%%a"=="!last!" ECHO %%a
 SET "last=%%a"
)
:break
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: I don't have your solution, but consider: find /i /v "A;;TE;*" "filetwo" >> outtwo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `if /?`; you are using the `IF [NOT] string1==string2 command` syntax pattern:

> ```
> string1==string2  Specifies a true condition if the specified text strings match.
> ```

**Nothing about wildcards**. However, you could make best of [`FINDSTR` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

> `FINDSTR` will set `%ERRORLEVEL%` as follows:
>
> - 0 (False) a match is found in at least one line of at least one file.
> - 1 (True) if a match is not found in any line of any file, (or if the file is not found at all).
> - 2 Wrong syntax
>
> An invalid switch will only print an error message in error stream.

**Regular Expressions** (Search for patterns of text)

`FINDSTR` can use the following metacharacters which have special meaning either as an operator or delimiter. `FINDSTR` support for regular expressions is *limited and non-standard*, only the following metacharacters are supported:

```
 .         Wildcard: any character
 *         Repeat: zero or more occurances of previous character or class
 ^         Line position: beginning of line
 $         Line position: end of line
           … etc.
```

Following code snippet could help:

```
SET "last="
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('sort "%filename1%"') DO (
  echo("%%a"|>NUL findstr "^\"A;;TE;.* ^\"W;;\"$"
  IF !errorlevel! EQU 0 (
      rem match:
      rem        either lines starting with A;;TE;
      rem            or lines equal to      W;;
      rem goto :break 
  ) else (
      IF "%%a"=="!last!" ECHO %%a
      SET "last=%%a"
  )
)
:break
```